# Controlling dropdown menu in vue multiselect

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Im using vue multiselect to create a searchable dropdown selection box. However due to the large number of options I want to control when the dropdown actually appears. e.g. after typing a certain number of characters into the search box. Is there a way to do this using v-select or v-multiselect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by using

```
@search-change="method"
```

where method looks something like this

```
method(option) {
  if (option.length < 2) {
    this.dropdown = [];
  } else {    
    this.dropdown = allOptions.slice[i, j];
```

Where we have `:options="dropdown"` and `allOptions` is the original list of options